# What cleaners are there in the market to use for Air duct duct cleaning?

Tags: air-conditioning, carpet, ducts

My air ducts need to be cleaned:
[image: Dirty ducts]

My house is near to the mountains so I' am unable to get a duct cleaning company to come to my house. Can any body suggest me some cleaners used for air duct cleaning? Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say 'cleaners', what exactly do you mean? Unless you have a major problem, it is not necessary to sanitize your ducts, just remove the buildup of dirt.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of options for air duct cleaning companies in the US market.
here are the things you should check before closing with [air duct cleaning company](http://www.pureairways.com/air-duct-cleaning/):

- if they have a license
- if they have insurance
- check online reviews